# Unable to use multiple Model in MVC based on any conditions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am creating a voting mechanism for my MVC application. user will be able to vote only after loged in. I have totally 3 tables tblQuestions(to populate the questions), tblAnswers(to populate the answers), tblQuestionAnswerUserResponses (to populate the user response.)tblAnswers have relation with tblQuestions. I have used the following code in the container in the HttpGet. This is my controller code.

```
   [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("VotingResult")]
        public ActionResult VotingResult(int personid)
        {
            List<Voting_Questions> QuesList = EpDObj.PopulateQuestions(); //Populate the list of questions
            CountofQuestionsDisplayed = QuesList.Count;
            ViewBag.Questions = QuesList; // Storing the list of questions in the viewbag
            List<Voting_Answers> Answers = EmcObj.Voting_Answers.ToList(); //Populate the list of answers
            return View(Answers);
        }
```

I am using the Voting_Answers as model in my view 
 My view is

```
@model  IEnumerable<EmployeeManagementDAL.Voting_Answers>


<h2>VotingResult</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<div>
    @foreach (var a in ViewBag.Questions)
    {
        <h4>@a.Questions</h4>
        <div>
            @foreach (var b in Model)
            {
                if (b.QuestionsID == a.id)
                {                                  
                @Html.RadioButton(b.AnswersOptions, new {Answerid= b.id, Questionid=a.id }) @b.AnswersOptions
                }
            }
        </div>
    } 
</div>
<br/>
<div >
    <input type="submit" value="Vote Now!!" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit your choices?');"/>
</div>
}
```

When the user go to this page for the very first time there will be no options selected. after selecting the options the values an clicking Save button will save the details to the third table and then he comes out of that page. Now if for the second time he reaches that page for editing, I want my page to render with those values in my tblQuestionAnswerResponses i.e I guess my model class of tblQuestionAnswerResponses to be used. In  that case can i use the same page for both cases i.e when the user vists the page for first time and also when second time the page is visited. Can I use multiple Model in MVC based on  conditions in my View.

Comment: If you want to use the same view for the initial voting and also for editing then your controller needs to be able to determine if the user has voted and you will need to send additional information to your view indicating the mode.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your ActionName attribute is unnecessary, as you have specified the same name that your action already has.
2. It would be cleaner to use a ViewModel instead of using the ViewBag. For starters, you'll get strong typing in your view, and it will also lend itself to easier testing.
3. If you make a ViewModel that represents what you want your view to display, then you can map back and forth between it and your domain models in your controller actions, and let them do the heavy lifing.